# DOMDocument getElementsByTagNameNS

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, domdocument

I've a problem with DOMDocument::getElementsByTagNameNS
when i try to replace a node or i try to modify the element one yes and one not are modified this is my example:

```
$xml = <<<EOD
<html xmlns:x="helloworld">
    <head>
        <title>ClasseAS - Home</title>
        <meta name="title" content="Hello World"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="hello"/>
        <x:hello/>
        <x:hello/>
        <x:hello/>
        <x:hello/>
    </head>
</html>
EOD;

$DOMDocument = new DOMDocument("1.0","utf-8");

    $DOMDocument->loadXML($xml);
    foreach ($DOMDocument->getElementsByTagNameNS("helloworld","*") as $element){
        if($element->localName == "hello"){
            $else = $element;
            $fragment = $DOMDocument->createDocumentFragment();
            $fragment->appendXML("<div id=\"hello\"></div>");
            $else->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment,$else);
        }
    }

    $HTML = $DOMDocument->saveXML();
    echo "<pre>".htmlentities($HTML)."</pre>";
?>
```

where is my error?
sorry in advance for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOMNodeList's(as returned by `$DOMDocument->getElementsByTagNameNS("helloworld","*")`) are live, when you replace a Node you modify the NodeList.

Some pseudo-code to clarify the behaviour:

```
foreach(liveNodeList as $index => $element){
 //1st loop
          [node0, node1, node2, node3]
   //$index 0_^
   //$element is node0

 //2nd loop
          [node1, node2, node3]
   //$index 1_______^
   //$element is node2

 //3rd loop
          [node1, node3]
   //$index 2____________^
    //end of loop
}
```

1. On the first loop `$index` is `0` and the NodeList contains 4 elements. The first  item of the original NodeList will be replaced(and also removed from the NodeList)
2. on the 2nd loop `$index` is 1, but the NodeList contains now only 3 elements(the first has been replaced/removed). `$element` now is the node with `$index` `1` in the NodeList, but the loop must again replace the node with the `$index` `0` to get the desired result. The 3rd  item of the original Nodelist will be replaced
3. on the 3rd loop `$index` is `2`, the NodeList contains now 2 elements, the `$index` points behind the end of the NodeList

possible solution:

Start the Node-replacement at the end of the NodeList:

```
for($i=$DOMDocument->getElementsByTagNameNS("helloworld","*")->length-1;
    $i>=0;--$i){
    $element=$DOMDocument->getElementsByTagNameNS("helloworld","*")->item($i);
    if($element->localName == "hello"){
        $fragment = $DOMDocument->createDocumentFragment();
        $fragment->appendXML("<div id=\"hello\"></div>");
        $element->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment,$element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the elements are selected using XPath, they can be manipulated more reliably in a `foreach` loop:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($DOMDocument);
$xpath->registerNamespace('h', 'helloworld');

foreach ($xpath->query('//h:hello') as $element) {
```